# laravel - choosing between helper or service provider

Tags: laravel

i want to make a search filter for like 15 models and for example if we consider the parameters are all the same for 15 models i Want to know should i make a helper for this not to repeat it or a service provider and i would be happy if u tell the difference and reason to choose one .
here is my search method as an example :

```
$result = DB::table('mod_dns_records')
        ->where('scheduled', 'N')
        ->where('scheduleTime', 0)
        ->where('domainId', $id)
        ->orWhere('deleteRow', 'Y')
        ->where('domainId', $id)
        ->get();
```

just to mention on am sending the result as an api if it makes any difference on choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

helper is not correct you must use service provider or repository pattern.

Comment: because your process dbal(database absraction layer).  We ise Helper functions code prevent duplication.